# What's the difference between Collision layers and Collision masks?

Tags: godot

In *PhysicsBody* and *PhysicsBody2D* in **GoDot**, there are two attributes called Mask (PhysicsBody| Collision| Collision and Mask). I noticed that a body collides with another body if they have a layer in common or a mask in common. But then, if there's already a collision layer, what's the purpose of the mask?

Answer (score 2):

thanks to [this answer](https://godotengine.org/qa/4010/whats-difference-between-collision-layers-collision-masks)

'collision mask` bit is for choosing *what layer should be collided*.

Let's assume we set `collision layer` and `mask layer` as below.

> Player node: collision layer is on 1st bit/mask layer is on 2nd,3rd bit 
> Enemy node: collision layer is on 2nd bit/mask layer is on 1st bit 
> Object node: collision layer is on 3rd bit/mask layer is on 1st bit

then

> Player mask(2) == Enemy layer(2) 
> Player mask(3) == Object layer(3) 
> so, Player can be collided with Enemy and Object.

but Enemy nodes do not collide each other or Object nodes, Because:

> Enemy mask(1) != Enemy layer(2) / Enemy mask(1) != Object layer(3)